# Get a particular string from text file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I need to get a particular string from a text file. the content of my file is below :

```
Components at each of the following levels must be
built before components at higher-numbered levels.

1.  SACHHYA-opkg-utils                        master@964c29cc453ccd3d1b28fb40bae8df11c0dc3b3c
    SACHHYA-web-SABARMATI-ap-page               master@3bdc2dc1e5cee745cfced370201352045cd57195
    SACHHYA-web-update-page                   master@24b0ffaad4d130ae5a2df0e470868846c7888392
    SACHHYAWebMonaco                          Release/MR1_2019/3.0.7-570+36a238d
    googletest-qc8017_32                   branches/googletest@2692
    LpmMfgTool                             Release/master/0.0.1-4+34833d6
    opensource-avahi-qc8017_32             Release/SACHHYA-master/v1.0-4-gb70507e
    opensource-OpenAvnuApple-qc8017_32     Release/SACHHYA-master/v1.0-1766-g1098033
    opensource-opkg-qc8017_32              Release/SACHHYA-dev/v0.3.6.2-2-gb1e1aba
    opensource-unzip-qc8017_32             Release/master/v6.0.0
    opensource-util-linux-qc8017_32        Release/SACHHYA-master/1.5.0-10+877ade5
    opensource-zip-qc8017_32               Release/master/v3.0.0
    product-startup                        Release/master/4.0.0-5+5179185
    ProductControllerCommon                master@a1e71509aaaa9cf7a9e70d4e9c7bfc80d76e13a2
    ProductUIAssets                        master@220944def647a72ce0194d43ef23f1d3fe146987
    proprietary-airplay2-qc8017_32         Release/SACHHYA-master/2.0.2-15-g88c1c1d
    SABARMATI-HSP-Images                     Release/master/4.4
    SABARMATI-Toolchain                      Release/master/4.4
    SABRMATILPM                             trunk@3408
    SABARMATILpmTools                        @3604
    SABARMATILpmUpdater                      Release/master/1.0.0-69+a38d6c8
```

The command that i am trying is :

```
awk /SACHHYAWebMonaco/ MyFile.txt
```

Using this command, I am able to get that particular line in which my string is present. Here is the result of the `awk` command :

```
SACHHYAWebMonaco                          Release/MR1_2019/3.0.7-570+36a238d
```

What I want to grep is only "3.0.7" (which is the version) from that line .

Can anyone have any suggestion to do that?

Comment: I don't see any "3.0.7" in content

Comment: @ShanavasM it is there, Look at that line which i specify as my output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `/` and `-` as field separators and print the third field.

This assumes the format of the lines and position of the information you seek will always be such.

```
$ awk -F[/-] '/SACHHYAWebMonaco/ {print $3}' file
3.0.7
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution

```
$ perl -F"[/-]" -lane ' print "$F[2]" if /SACHHYAWebMonaco/ ' sachhya.txt
3.0.7
```